# Shared-memory of the assembly references in multiprocessing

Tags: c#, multithreading, process, multiprocessing

I use WCF to open multi Endpoint services add host it in Windows Server, each one loaded in a separate process and the process launcher using assembly1.dll, assembly2.dll, assembly3.dll ....., when loading 5 lancher (5 Endpoint ) i observe duplicated size of assembly references in memory, so how to make the 5 processes consume shared assemblies.
[image: the 5 processes consume (no shared / shared) assemblies]

Comment: What OS you are using and does that OS support what you want? Clearly you are not asking about Windows... Please [edit] post with that information, ideally adding some links explaining OS support of your "desired situation" and possibly listing some benefits you expect to achieve by the change.

Comment: If you are on windows, use [ngen.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/ngen-exe-native-image-generator#Memory).

Comment: If you use windows - what is the logic that gets you the idea multiple processes would not require multiple copies of the assembly in memory, given that processes are memory boundaries? You do not want them to be isolated, do not isolate them - which means load them into one process. This is windows 101 - actually OS 101. That is what a process does: Isolate memory.

Comment: @TomTom The executable code of the assemblies is inmutable and can be shared between processes. That's why you'll need ngen to have a native image and not generated for every process by the just-in-time compiler. You can see then in task manager/process explorer that the processes will have shared memory.